# Strange popup window trying to send ether when I run aleth zero. What should I do?

Tags: ether, dapps, cpp-ethereum, alethzero, alethone

I ran aleth zero and mined with aleth one a while back.  I had mined some ether from a mining pool.

Now when I run aleth zero (updated client for windows), I get an annoying and unstoppable pop up window that says: 
Transaction

DApp is attempting to send 1.048 ether to a recipient ______, with additional network fees of up to 1.5 finney.  Maximum total cost is 1.05 ether.

I have never made a contract and I don't think I tried sending ether to anyone in the past.  How can I get rid of this popup and why exactly is it happening?

Answer (score 2):

You might have a dapp running as part of the alethzero browser or anything else that connects via json-rpc.